# ORA-00904 invalid identifer error when using alias

Tags: oracle-12c, alias, identifier

I'm trying to return a product of two subqueries, and thought I'd make life easier by aliasing each of the subqueries, then divide the two aliases to get the number I'm after, like this:

`select distinct
(select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest
  where ORG_UNIT_NO IN (1904, 1830,1831, 1902)) as Ha_IN_RKB, 
(select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest) as Ha_total,
ROUND(  (Ha_IN_RKB / Ha_total) ,3)
from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest`

but this results in a 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" error (Oracle doesn't like `Ha_IN_RKB` or `Ha_total` ).

Re-writing the query as follows works, but is rather bulky:
`select distinct
(select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest
  where ORG_UNIT_NO IN (1904, 1830,1831, 1902)) Ha_IN_RKB, 
(select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest)  Ha_total,
ROUND(  ((select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest
  where ORG_UNIT_NO IN (1904, 1830,1831, 1902)) / 
  (select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest)) ,3) as RKB_pct
from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest`

Anybody know why I can't just make this `ROUND(  (Ha_IN_RKB / Ha_total) ,3)` work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases cannot be used directly. You have to abstract them out using a nested subquery or derived table.

```
with t as (
    select
    (select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) 
       from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest
      where ORG_UNIT_NO IN (1904, 1830,1831, 1902)) 
         as Ha_IN_RKB, 
    (select SUM(pest.AREA_HA) 
       from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.PEST_INFESTATION_POLY pest) 
         as Ha_total
    from dual)
select t.ha_in_rkb, t.ha_total, ROUND(t.Ha_IN_RKB/t.Ha_total,3) from t;
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! In this case, would it be accurate to say that you've used the derived table approach, i.e. t being a derived / temporary table ?

Comment: Yes. "t" is effectively a temporary, derived table.